# Visual Studio Code HTML snippets no longer working

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I've been using [HTML Snippets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=abusaidm.html-snippets) for HTML snippets in VSC for a while, however in my most recent project these have stopped working. I've tried researching why this is, and I can't find a straight answer on how to fix it. Being unable to use HTML snippets is severely limiting the speed of my html coding.

Comment: looking at the extension page it looks a lot like Emmet, see VSC docs pages

Comment: download the v0.1.0 vsix file, unzip the file and use the `snippets,json` file inside and copy the content to your local `html.json` snippet file

Comment: it has stopped working in 2017-Dec, I don't call this recent

Comment: It was still working for me until yesterday, hence why I said recently.

Comment: you can add all the snippets from the extension (v0.1.0) to the `django-html` user snippets file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bro, the author has disabled this extension

> #### Update 5
>
> Disabling this extension as its functionality has been absorbed by VS Code main html extension.

## Download

You can get the previous working version [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/abusaidm/vsextensions/html-snippets/0.1.0/vspackage), just remove the previously installed extension, also do not update this extension after installation

Comment: How do I enable the vscode main html extension then? I've definitely not got any snippets right now.

Comment: @Evelyn see my edit of my answer

Comment: I overlooked the fact I'm working in django-html which VSC identifies as a different language mode as html, so my solution ended up being adding django html to the emmet included languages which appears to have worked and snippets are now working again.